# Replace nth String

Tags: replace

I'm new here. I wanted to ask a question given that I didn't find what I want in the search.

Here is the question via the problem and output. Here is the flow:

```
public class change{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = 9999 + rand.nextInt(190000);
        int replace = 1 + rand.nextInt(5);
        String numcon = Integer.toString(number);
        String display = ????numcon????;
```

What I want is to replace a character in certain or nth position of numcon to "_". Like this:
Let's say numcon has randomized to "1234567" and replace is randomized between 1 to 6. This should what System.out.print(display) looks like.

```
replace / display
1       / "_23456"
2       / "1_3456"
3       / "12_456"
4       / "123_56"
5       / "1234_6"
6       / "12345_"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class change{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = 9999 + rand.nextInt(190000);
    int replace = 1 + rand.nextInt(5);
    byte[] numcon = Integer.toString(number).getBytes();
    numcon[replace] = '_';
    String display = new String(numcon);
```